# Clear the Activity History Stack once inside Main activity

Tags: android

I want to clear the HistoryStack once I have started my MainActivity that is inside its `oncreate()` method of `Main`.

Due to some issues I can't use `android:noHistory="true"` because it creates problem for my gPlus signing in, also can't use `finish()` `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` for similar reasons.

I only want it to be removes in particular case that is when inside Main, otherwise it should be there on History stack.

Once in Main all history stack should be clear and over pressing back the app should exit. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For no recents activities use `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in desire activity.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a BroadcastReceiver in all activities you want to finish.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private FinishReceiver finishReceiver;
private static final String ACTION_FINISH =
        "com.mypackage.MyActivity.ACTION_FINISH";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    finishReceiver = new FinishReceiver();
    registerReceiver(finishReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_FINISH));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    unregisterReceiver(finishReceiver);
}

private final class FinishReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_FINISH))
            finish();
    }
}
}
```

You can close those Activitys by calling

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_FINISH));
```

Check this example for details:

http://www.hrupin.com/2011/10/how-to-finish-all-activities-in-your-android-application-through-simple-call